# How can I get the full text of the active window in an SSMS addin?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I'm attempting to get the text of the active window in SSMS via an addin developed through VS2012. I can see the [EnvDTE.Window.Selection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.window.selection.aspx) property contains some information on the selected text, but I also want to be able to access the full text.

1. Anyone know how this is possible?
2. Does anyone also know how you can set the text of the active window, both selected and full text?

Thanks

Comment: Out of interest, what will your SSMS add-in be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answers:

1. You can set the text by simply assigning the **Text** property. Be warned that it gets a little weird with some formatting it automatically does.
2. You can just do a **SelectAll** call and then access the **Text** property to get all of the text on the active window.
3. The type of object returned by the **Selection** property is a **TextSelection** object.